# Cause and Solution to Iterator Access Violation

Tags: c++, iterator

Why does attempting to output a `TCHAR[]` from an iterator cause an access violation and how can I remedy this and still use iterators? I don't understand what is going wrong?

```
struct FileInfo
{
    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
};

void iter()
{
    std::vector<FileInfo> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        v.push_back({ _T("abc") });

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        OutputDebugString(_T("Ok "));
        OutputDebugString(v[i].path);
        OutputDebugString(_T("\n"));
    }

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++){
        OutputDebugString(_T("Bad "));
        OutputDebugString((LPTSTR)*it->path); // CAUSES runtime error here
        OutputDebugString(_T("\n"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`*it->path` evaluates to a `TCHAR`, not a `TCHAR*`.

Casting a `TCHAR` to `LPTSTR` is not right. Casting a `TCHAR*` to `LPTSTR` is OK.

You can use:

```
OutputDebugString((LPTSTR)it->path);
```

or

```
OutputDebugString((LPTSTR)(*it).path));
```

Answer (score 1):

The program crashes with the following message :

> Unhandled exception at 0x778180E0 (ntdll.dll) in test.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x00000061.

Interesting thing : `0x00000061` is the ascii value of the character `a` which is the first character of the string you want to output. By doing : 
`*it->path` you get the first character of the string in `path`. Then when you do 
`(LPTSTR)*it->path` you cast the first character of the string to a pointer. Hence the error : `reading location 0x00000061`